# React framer-motion objects increasing in size when dragging

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

So as the question says my objects are increasing in size when I drag then and I'm really not sure why, here is the code can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Its a bunch of circle images which just move around a bit on the screen and grow slightly smaller on click but only while they are being dragged.

React Page

```
import React from 'react';
import { useMediaQuery} from 'react-responsive';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { Button } from '../../globalStyles';
import CodeCircle1 from '../../images/CodeCircle1.png';
import CodeCircle2 from '../../images/CodeCircle2.png';
import CodeCircle3 from '../../images/CodeCircle3.png';
import CodeCircle4 from '../../images/CodeCircle4.png';
import { Section, Container, ColumnLeft, ColumnRight, Image, } from './AboutPage.elements';

const AboutPage = () => {
  const fadeLeft = {
    hidden: { opacity: 0, x: -100 },
    visible: { opacity: 1, x: 0 }
  };
  const Desktop = ({ children }) => {
    const isDesktop = useMediaQuery({ minWidth: 768 })
    return isDesktop ? children : null
  }
  const Mobile = ({ children }) => {
    const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ maxWidth: 767 })
    return isMobile ? children : null
  }
  return (
    <Section>
      <Container>
        <ColumnLeft>
          <motion.h1
            initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
            transition={{ duration: 1 }}
          >
            Josh Lawler
          </motion.h1>
          <motion.p
            variants={fadeLeft}
            initial='hidden'
            animate='visible'
            transition={{ duration: 1 }}
          >
            I'm a UK computer science graduate who is profficent in languages such as Python, Javascript and Java.
          </motion.p>
          <Button
            whileHover={{ scale: 1.05 }}
            whileTap={{
              scale: 0.95,
              backgroundColor: '#67F6E7',
              border: 'none',
              color: '#000'
            }}
            initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, transition: { duration: 1.5 } }}
          >
            Get Started
          </Button>
        </ColumnLeft>
        <Desktop>
        <ColumnRight>
          <Image
            src={CodeCircle1}
            alt='CodeCircle'
            whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
            drag={true}
            dragConstraints={{ left: 0, right: 250, top: 0, bottom: 50 }}
            initial={{ opacity: 0, y: -100 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0, transition: { duration: 1 } }}
          />
          <Image
            src={CodeCircle2}
            alt='CodeCircle'
            whileTap={{ scale: 0.6 }}
            drag={true}
            dragConstraints={{ left: 50, right: 0, top: 0, bottom: 50 }}
            initial={{ opacity: 0, x: 100 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, x: 0, transition: { duration: 1 } }}
          />  
          <Image
            src={CodeCircle3}
            alt='CodeCircle'
            whileTap={{ scale: 0.8 }}
            drag={true}
            dragConstraints={{ left: 0, right: 250, top: 0, bottom: 50 }}
            initial={{ opacity: 0, x: -100 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, x: 0, transition: { duration: 1 } }}
          />
          <Image
            src={CodeCircle4}
            alt='CodeCircle'
            whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
            drag={true}
            dragConstraints={{ left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0 }}
            initial={{ opacity: 0, y: 100 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0, transition: { duration: 1 } }}
          />
        </ColumnRight>
        </Desktop>
        <Mobile>
        <ColumnRight>
          <Image
            src={CodeCircle1}
            alt='CodeCircle'
            whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
            drag={true}
            dragConstraints={{ left: 0, right: 50, top: 0, bottom: 50 }}
            initial={{ opacity: 0, y: -100 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0, transition: { duration: 1 } }}
          />
          <Image
            src={CodeCircle2}
            alt='CodeCircle'
            whileTap={{ scale: 0.6 }}
            drag={true}
            dragConstraints={{ left: 25, right: 0, top: 0, bottom: 25 }}
            initial={{ opacity: 0, x: 100 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, x: 0, transition: { duration: 1 } }}
          />  
          <Image
            src={CodeCircle3}
            alt='CodeCircle'
            whileTap={{ scale: 0.8 }}
            drag={true}
            dragConstraints={{ left: 0, right: 25, top: 0, bottom: 10 }}
            initial={{ opacity: 0, x: -100 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, x: 0, transition: { duration: 1 } }}
          />
          <Image
            src={CodeCircle4}
            alt='CodeCircle'
            whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
            drag={true}
            dragConstraints={{ left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0 }}
            initial={{ opacity: 0, y: 100 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0, transition: { duration: 1 } }}
          />
        </ColumnRight>
        </Mobile>
      </Container>
    </Section>
  )
}
```

Styling Page

```
export default AboutPage;


import styled from 'styled-components';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

export const Section = styled.section`
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #101522;
`;

export const Container = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 3rem calc((100vw - 1300px) / 2);
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    grid-grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
`;

export const ColumnLeft = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 5rem 2rem;
  h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
  }
  p {
    margin: 2rem 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.1;
  }
`;

export const Image = styled(motion.img)`
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
`;

export const ColumnRight = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  ${Image}:nth-child(1) {
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
  }
  ${Image}:nth-child(2) {
    top: 170px;
    right: 10px;
  }
  ${Image}:nth-child(3) {
    top: 350px;
    left: 100px;
  }
  ${Image}:nth-child(4) {
    bottom: 100px;
    right: 75px;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    position: relative;
    ${Image}:nth-child(1) {
      top: 10px;
      left: -20px;
    }
    ${Image}:nth-child(2) {
      top: 170px;
      right: 50px;
    }
    ${Image}:nth-child(3) {
      top: 350px;
      left: -10px;
    }
    ${Image}:nth-child(4) {
      bottom: 100px;
      right: 25px;
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: nope, I still haven't worked it out it's like this on my site still, not a major issue just annoying

Answer (score 0):

You have a `whileTap` property set on every image. This means that when the image is tapped (and then dragged), the set of transformation defined in `whileTap` are applied.

In your case

```
whileTap={{ scale: 0.95 }}
```

Means that meanwhile the mouse (or finger) is pressed on an element, the element itself is scaled at 95% of its size, hence it will become smaller.

Simply remove the scale property from `whileTap` to prevent that effect.